# Text is not appearing in link button html

Tags: html, css, button

I added some link buttons in my website that using code from w3schools. While testing them in internet explorer [they look fine](https://image.prntscr.com/image/iv5-3Dc1QjKr1ksbuL8w6g.png) but on Firefox and Chrome the [text seems to have disappeared](https://image.prntscr.com/image/QFF9L4jkSd6a90s_PB5hQQ.png).

Here is my code : (I'm kinda new so don't be harsh)
(for some reason stackoverflow strips half my html code. Here is the pastebin www.pastebin.com/raw/H50UgpCB )

ps would be nice if an admin formatted this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <span id="chromeFix"></span> 
        <title>FivosM Projects</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">

        <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n4.js"></script>
            <style>

                body {
                    font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                h1, p, h3 {
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
                    -webkit-background-clip: text;
                    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;   
                }
                a:link, a:visited {
                    background-color: #f44336;
                    color: blue;
                    padding: 3px 6px;
                    text-align: center; 
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                }

                a:hover, a:active {
                    background-color: red;
                }
        </style>
    </head>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            $(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
        </script>

  <body>
      <div class = "body animated bounceInDown">
            <h1 class="bounce">My Projects: </h1>
            <h3> Software: </h3>
            <p><b>Pinger:</b> <a href="google.com" target="_blank"> Download </a> &nbsp; <a href="google.com" target="_blank"> Github </a></p>
            <h3> Games: </h3>
            <p><b>HellBlocks:</b> <a href="google.com"> Itch.io page </a></p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge does not like shadows above 4px for some reason

Converting this:

```
.shadow {
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #d3d3d3;
 }
```

To this :

```
.shadow {
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d3d3d3;
 }
```

Fixed everything... I still don't know why that's happening, maybe it's my edge client bugging.

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be that you coded :

`-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

Change that to `-webkit-text-fill-color: red;`  and see what it does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @FivosCapone Cool. Say thanks by up voting or accepting the answers proposed  to you ;-)  Glad it helped you.

Comment: I upvoted both of you but i need to reach 15 rep first.

Comment: @FivosCapone Cool. Welcome at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` in

```
h1, p, h3 {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;   
}
```

edit: This makes sense as IE does not support -webkit-text-fill-color ([see here](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-text-fill-color)).